# WIF - How do I update FederationMetadata.xml on production environment?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wif, claims-based-identity

I need to deploy a STS and an ASP.NET RP for several clients, all together they form a product, and of course I will need to update the STS FederationMetadata.xml with each client's data and also update the RP reference to the STS.

How can I accomplish this on a production environment? Do I have to install WIF's SDK on each client so I can use FedUtil.exe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found that I don't need to FedUtil on RP side, just setting wsFederation.issuer, wsFederation.realm, trustedIssuers, audienceUris on the web.config and that is enough. FederationMetadata.xml is not necessary once in production unless you want to update metadata periodically which I don't.

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: it does, but I wonder if you could provide some more detail- in the trustedIssuers section, how can you retrieve the certificate's thumbprint? I saw some suggestions of using the Fedutil.exe for that, but like you, I'm reluctant to do that. simply copying the value from the certificate's tumbprint in the certificate store did not work for me...

Comment: Once you get the thumbprint, it is necessary to remove all spaces and then to change everything to uppercase.  An easy way to do this is to use Visual Studio and search for " " and replace with "", followed by selecting the thumbprint and doing a CTRL-SHIFT+U to make everything uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

On the RP side, you need to FedUtil each instance.

On the STS side, if you are using something like ADFS, you can simply click the "Update from FederationMetadata" link".

Comment: But is there any other way to install FedUtil.exe but to install WIF SDK? Thanks!

Comment: In the SDK, there are 4 files related to FedUtil. You could just copy them over? I'm guessing it also requires the Windows.IdentityModel dll?

Comment: When you say it didn't work, could you please provide some more details of what went wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail, I had already tried copying FedUtil but an error ocurred when I run it. As soon as I can get to the test environment I will give you more detail.

Comment: Thanks but the answer I marked was enough for me. Sorry for the late answer.